# Execute AquaMacs buffer that has "from __future__ import ..."

Tags: python, python-2.7, emacs, aquamacs

Running AquaEmacs, I want to execute a buffer (C-c C-c) in Python.

The buffer starts with:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

The execution in AquaEmacs starts with:

```
import sys,imp
if'test_one_liners' in sys.modules:
   imp.reload(test_one_liners)
else:
   import test_one_liners
```

where test_one_liners.py is my file.   This gives this error:

```
 SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file
```

Anyone know where and how to fix this?

Let me add the information again to make it clear.

Create this buffer:

```
 from __future__ import print_function

 print("Hello")
```

Use File/Change Buffer Mode/Python to make it Python and C-c C-c to execute it; it need not be saved.  The buffer is written to some temporary file and fails with `SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file`.   The traceback includes a generated file which contains a reference to a temp file.   What should happen instead it printing Hello.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in `python-mode.el` which is fixed in the current release. It looks like aquamacs is bundled with an [older version of `python-mode.el`](https://github.com/davidswelt/aquamacs-emacs/tree/master/aquamacs/src/site-lisp/edit-modes/python-mode).

The bug report is here: [bug #1063884](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1063884) and the fix [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~python-mode-devs/python-mode/python-mode/revision/1106).

You should update your python-mode.el package.

Answer (score 1):

1. You say `from __future__ import print_function`, but the error message talks about `from __future__ imports` --- Note the `s` at the end of that.
2. You say that " test_one_liners.py is my file".  And you say that `from __future__ import print_function` is at the beginning of "the buffer".  But the error messages says that it doesn't find that incantation at the beginning of file `test_one_liners.py`.  Perhaps your current buffer, which has that incantation, is not for that file?

But if I had to guess, I'd guess the problem is the apparent typo in #1.  ("Apparent", because you might just have mistyped the post, and the incantation might be correct in the file.)

Comment: 1.  Yes, the error message is in English, so it says "imports must occur at the beginning of the file"; the singular would be bad grammar.  2.  Yes, the *buffer* is executed, with C-c C-c.  The name of the file is relevant only to show it is in python mode.  Your guess is appreciated, though it likely to do with the exec file.  I will add more information.

Answer (score 1):

As it was said, this is fixed in current trunk.

https://launchpad.net/python-mode

When checking your example, get "ImportError: No module named test_one_liners", which is to expect.

Second example prints nicely "Hello".